# Getting an item with image field not working

Tags: rest, spfx

I wrote this code to get items from a SharePoint list that contains an image field:

```
private _getApps(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.properties.listId) {
      return this.context.spHttpClient.get(
        `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}` +
        `/_api/web/lists/GetById(id='${this.properties.listId}')/items`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsonResponse) => jsonResponse.value.map(
          (item: any) => { return { title: item.Title, description: item.AppDescription, imageUrl: item.AppLogo? JSON.parse(item.AppLogo).serverRelativeUrl: "" }}) 
        )
        .then((items) => this.setState({ vivaApps: items }));
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
```

It used to work fine, but my images didn't look nice. I edited the items in the quick edit view, now the value of item.AppLogo doesn't get my the item url anymore, now it gets me this:

```
"{"fileName":"Reserved_ImageAttachment_[7]_[AppLogo][8]_[image1][1]_[7].png"}"
```

I haven't changed anything else. Before I modify the images in the quick view, I used to get the actual url as part of the AppLogo value, and I was parsing that value with JSON.parse to get the image url. Now it seems that it is broken.

If I try to run this query:
[https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mywebsite/_api/web/lists/GetById(id='3a1b02aa-5562-46a6-93e7-d4cca3c1a48b')/items?$select=Title,AppDescription,AppLogo/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=AppLogo](https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mywebsite/_api/web/lists/GetById(id=%273a1b02aa-5562-46a6-93e7-d4cca3c1a48b%27)/items?$select=Title,AppDescription,AppLogo/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=AppLogo)

I get back "The field or property 'AppLogo' does not exist." ... I know 100% that the internal name of my image field is AppLogo .. Not sure why after editing the field using quick view, everything got corrupted!

If I just run this query it would work:
[https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mywebsite/_api/web/lists/GetById(id='3a1b02aa-5562-46a6-93e7-d4cca3c1a48b')/items?$select=Title,AppDescription,AppLogo](https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mywebsite/_api/web/lists/GetById(id=%273a1b02aa-5562-46a6-93e7-d4cca3c1a48b%27)/items?$select=Title,AppDescription,AppLogo)

But the AppLogo value would be this:

```
"{"fileName":"Reserved_ImageAttachment_[7]_[AppLogo][8]_[image1][1]_[7].png"}"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/SharePoint-List-isn-t-returning-image-field/td-p/1201162

The image column isn't fully supported by the SharePoint connector.

You can try one of the following:

1. Instead of storing the image data directly in the list, you could store the images as files in a SharePoint document library and store the URL to the image file in your list.
2. You can store the raw image data in a multiline text column.
3. You can try adding a Text type column (called "FileName") in your SharePoint List to store the image file name then within your app, add a connection to your SharePoint Library as a data source.

Let me know if any of these help.